# Can we we publish web application project to IIS website to NLB production server (public IP) using Visual Studio 2013 publish

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-server-2012, webdeploy-3.6

I am trying to build CI using Teamcity and want to test using visual studio 2013 publish method to check publishing is working without any problem on NLB production Server (PUBLIC IP). I installed

1.Enabled the IIS Web Management role feature 
   2.WebDeploy 3.6 
3. Both Services 1. Web Deployment Agent Service & 2.Web Management Service are running on  NLB Server 
4. Did Configure Web Deploy Publishing on Website and all details.

When I tried to Publish from my development machine it gives me Error:
Could not connect to the remote computer (XYZ-02). Make sure that the remote computer name is correct and that you are able to connect to that computer. Learn more aT: ERROR _DESTINATION_INVALID. The remote error could not be resolved:
not sure Issue is with the port 8172 is open on the web server. How to check the port is open from my development pc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ip address instead of server name fixed my Issue Even port 8172 was open   :[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use telnet to test the port:

```
   Telnet XYZ-02 8172
```

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/187628/using-telnet-to-test-port-3389-functionality